# set date in EST - Android

Tags: java, android, date, timezone, timezone-offset

The idea is to build an event (custom class Event) where the user can write the time he wants the event to be at in hours and minutes and select the date from a calendarView.
So I get the date he picked from the view and the time he wants the event to begin at and put them into the event object. Problem is that when I create it it will set the date to GMT-3 (my Default), but I want the date to be in EST. Since the app will be mainly used by people using the EST format, if I create the event it will display it wrong for them and viceversa, and if I want to set up notifications for these events they won't be correct.
Is there a way to create a date in EST?

In this way, if they create a date in EST and I read it from my phone, it will display it in my timezone won't it?

Comment: I'll just recommend reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537106/is-it-always-a-good-idea-to-store-time-in-utc-or-is-this-the-case-where-storing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## tl;dr

Capture input.

```
Instant instant = 
    OffsetDateTime.of( LocalDate.of( 2016 , 1 , 2 ) , 
                       LocalTime.of( 12 , 34 , 56 ) , 
                       ZoneOffset.ofHours( -3 ) 
                     )
                  .toInstant() ;
```

Generate output for presentation in any time zone with any [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html).

```
String output = 
    instant.atZone( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) )
           .format( DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL )
                                     .withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) 
                  ) ;
```

## Use proper time zone names

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name). Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are not true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

## Offset versus time zone

An [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) is a number of hours and minutes and seconds different from UTC that a particular locality of people use in setting the time on their clocks, the [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time).

A time zone is an offset *plus* a set of rules for handling anomalies.

So `GMT-3` is *not* your time zone, it is your offset. Your time zone might be [`America/Buenos_Aires`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires), [`Antarctica/Rothera`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antarctica/Rothera), or such.

Since a time zone provides more information and more features, always use a time zone in preference over a mere offset.

Tip: Always write out an offset with **padding zeros** and with **both hour and minutes** separated by colon. The other variations are permitted by the ISO 8601 standard, but are sometimes not supported in various protocols or software systems. So use `-03:00` rather than `-3`.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Do not use the notoriously troublesome old legacy classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. Avoid `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, and such. Now supplanted by the java.time classes.

## `LocalDate` & `LocalTime`

The `LocalDate` and `LocalTime` types in java.time represent a date-only or time-of-day-only value, and without time zone. Use these to collect data from your widgets. “Local” means “un-zoned”, lacking in offset or time zone meaning.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2016 , 1 , 2 );
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 12 , 34 , 56 );
```

## `OffsetDateTime`

If all we have is an offset of three hours rather than a full time zone, interpret that pair of `LocalDate` & `LocalTime` as a `OffsetDateTime` object with a [`ZoneOffset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) object.

```
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofHours( -3 );
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.of( ld , lt , offset );
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

If we do have a time zone in mind, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Buenos_Aires" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z );
```

## `Instant`

Do much of your business logic, data storage, and data exchange in UTC. Apply offset or time zone only where needed such as presentation to the user.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

You can extract a `Instant` object from the other types.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
```

Adjust the instant into any other time zones you may desire.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtNewYork = instant.atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) );
ZonedDateTime zdtParis = instant.atZone( ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" ) );
ZonedDateTime zdtAuckland = instant.atZone( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) );
```

These objects all represent the same moment, the same point on the timeline. They are different only in that we are viewing the same moment through the lens of each locality’s [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time).

## Strings

Keep in mind that strings are not date-time values; they are a *representation* in text of the date-time value.

So a date-time object can *generate* a String in any format you desire. You can specify a custom format. But generally best to let java.time automatically [localize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) for you.

To localize, specify:

- [`FormatStyle`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be.
- [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine (a) the human language for translation of name of day, name of month, and such, and (b) the cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, and such.

Example:

```
Locale l = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ; 
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( l );
String output = zdt.format( f );
```

Note that `Locale` is orthogonal to time zone, *completely* unrelated. You can have a French presentation of an `Pacific/Auckland` zoned value, or a Hindu presentation of a `Europe/Copenhagen` zoned value.

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as `Interval`, `YearWeek`, `YearQuarter`, and more.

Comment: Really useful and detailed explanation. For some reason I am unable to import the java.time fw into my project though, so I can't put this in practice :( 

I've been using Date variables parsed from Calendar values so far. Should I edit the Event class and associations so it is instead done with Instants?

Comment: @BrunoMorales Reread the second-to-last paragraph about Android and ThreeTenABP. And, yes, I would use `Instant` objects in your class. The old classes really are that bad. You may also want to track the user’s desired/expected offset or time zone; depends on the details of your scenario. Just remember to separate the ideas of basic data which should generally be in UTC versus presentation which can have a time zone applied.