# How to select all records by next date Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In this method, I need to select all records by `RenewalDate`. To achieve this I have method something like this.

```
public class Subscription
{
    public DateTimeOffset? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? RenewalDate { get; set; }
    public string SubscriptionType { get; set; }
}

public async ValueTask<List<Subscription>> SelectAllSubscriptionRenewingOnNextDay()
{
    DateTimeOffset tomorrow = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);

    var subscriptionsRenewalTomorrow =
        await this.CustomerSubscriptions
                  .Include(c => c.Customer)
                  .Where(sub => sub.RenewalDate != null && 
                                sub.RenewalDate >= tomorrow.UtcDateTime && 
                                sub.RenewalDate < tomorrow.UtcDateTime.AddDays(1))
                  .ToListAsync();

    return subscriptionsRenewalTomorrow;
}
```

In the database there is a record, its value for `RenewalDate` is `2025-02-20 05:30:00+05:30`. But that row is not retrieved.

How to get all the rows with a renewal tomorrow?

Answer (score 0):

+05:30 shows you are saving datetime in database as local time, so Please try with the local datetime instead of  UTC date while filtering.

```
 public async ValueTask<List<Subscription>> SelectAllSubscriptionRenewingOnNextDay()
{
     
    DateTimeOffset tomorrow = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(1).ToLocalTime();

    var subscriptionsRenewalTomorrow =
        await this.CustomerSubscriptions.Include(c => c.Customer)
            .Where(sub => sub.RenewalDate.HasValue && 
                          sub.RenewalDate >= tomorrow.Date && 
                          sub.RenewalDate < tomorrow.Date.AddDays(1))
            .ToListAsync();

    return subscriptionsRenewalTomorrow;
}
```

Also it is advisable to store UTC datetime in database,

[Is it always a good idea to store time in UTC or is this the case where storing in local time is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537106/is-it-always-a-good-idea-to-store-time-in-utc-or-is-this-the-case-where-storing)

Comment: Cannot write DateTimeOffset with Offset=05:30:00 to PostgreSQL type 'timestamp with time zone', only offset 0 (UTC) is supported. Note that it's not possible to mix DateTimes with different Kinds in an array/range. See the Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior AppContext switch to enable legacy behavior. 

the above exception message is shown

Comment: try with ToUniversalTime() method